# Invoke method call asynchronously without blocking main thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous

I have a scenario where the  spring-boot application have to download a file from downstream application and pass it to the client. The API also needs to update a read flag in the database without blocking the response(main-thread).

A basic async use-case is what I thought of and implemented in the respective API. But, I am getting a behavioral issue with @Async. The annotation is able to spawn a new thread , but its blocking the main-thread and holding the response. The expectation was to return without holding the main-thread.
***Actually, the async update is the last operation of main-thread, and I guess due to that @Async is blocking the main-thread.***

Can anyone please suggest a better solution of this scenario.

**Calling class**

```
ResponseEntity<byte[]> parsedResponse = retrieverService.retrieve(id,"html");

retrieverService.update(id);

return parsedResponse;
```

**Async method**

```
@Override
@Async("updateTaskExecutor")
public void update(String id) {
    LOG.info("Updating data for metaTagId: {}", id);
    db.updateReadFlag(id);
}
```

**Async Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "updateTaskExecutor")
    public Executor updateTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(100);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("UpdateTaskClient-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is holding the main thread it isn't async. How do you know it is blocking the main thread?

Comment: @M.Deinum I used debugger to pause the activity in async method, and I was expecting response. The response didn't came till I resumed the debugger. Hence, it was blocking the main thread.

Comment: Thus it isn't asyncronous and your async configuration isn't working. As I stated if it is holding it isn't async.

Comment: @M.Deinum , but I can see different thread name(UpdateTaskClient -) in the logs. Is it possible that new thread is spawned, but its working at sync with main thread?

Comment: Also @M.Deinum, could you help me to fix the async configurations

Comment: Depending on the debugger it might hold all threads, so stopping something in the debugger might not be the best thing to do. You are probably better of using a `Thread.sleep(long time)` instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks for the prompt help. You were correct. Debugger was holding all the threads. Thread sleep worked to rectify the functionality. The Configurations are working fine, and I am able to make asynchronous calls.

Comment: had the same problem. Turns out the debugger in intellij paused all threads when one of them hit a breakpoint. running instead of debugging showed that my implementation was correct.

Answer (score 0):

The Configurations were correct. I was using debugger to check the parallelism. As suggested by @M. Deinum, its not the correct way to check parallelism. After using Thread.sleep() , I could see that asynchronous calls are working as expected. I am able to send the response back, while performing an update query asynchronously.

Comment: where you sleep the main-thread after the call to `db.updateReadFlag(id);` ? `CountDownLatch`  may be a better option than sleep